# Margin Shifting: <ul> jitters when hover function initiated.

Tags: javascript, html, css

This is just a theory based question. I am fairly new to programming and was wondering why this happens within HTML.

I'm making an HTML based resume where when I have a mouse pointer hover over my `ul` it will activate a function such as this.

```
$("li#about").hover(function(){
  $("#content1").toggle();
});
```

**The Issue** While hovering over my selector when my #content was no longer hidden, my margins between my header and `ul` box would cause jittering within the page.

I went from:

```
<header>
  <h1>Ryan Anderson</h1>
  <h3>Developer</h3>
</header>

<body>
 <div class="clearfix"> 
  <div class="column">
    <ul>
      <li id="about"> <span>About Me</span> </li>
      <li id='education'> <span>Education</span></li>
      <li id='info'> <span>Experience</span></li>
      <li id='ref'> <span>References</span></li>
    </ul>
  <div class="clr"></div>
 </div>
```

to:

```
<header>
   <h1>Ryan Anderson</h1>
   <h3>Developer</h3>

 <body>
  <div class="clearfix"> 
   <div class="column">
     <ul>
       <li id="about"> <span>About Me</span> </li>
       <li id='education'> <span>Education</span></li>
       <li id='info'> <span>Experience</span></li>
       <li id='ref'> <span>References</span></li>
     </ul>
   <div class="clr"></div>
  </div>
</header>
```

**My questions**:

- What was the reason for the sporadic jittering and how did wrapping my `ul` within the `header` tag prevent this from occurring?
- Is my solution proper etiquette? If not, what would you recommend?
- If you have any good recommendations for coding etiquette please post links in comments.

*sing-song* Being new, I know my code must look like poo. Regardless I added a fiddle for you.

Thanks for the read! I apologize in advance for the ugly code. I posted a JSFiddle as well, figured it would help any other newbies to conceptualize what i'm asking. This fiddle is **without correction** Just change the closing header tag to where I specified above to see the results.

My Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/dgibbins1/cwn6ws02/4/

```
header{
    background: #5a4c1c;
    border-radius:10px;
    opacity:0.85;
    padding:1px 0;
}

h1{
    margin: 0 0;
    color: white;
    padding-left:10px;
}

h3{
    color:#dad6c7;
    padding-left: 31px;
}

body{
    background:#dad6c7;

}


ul{
    list-style-type:none;
    padding: 0px 15px;
    margin: 50px 0;
}

span{
    color:white;
}

li{
    font-family:Helvetica;
}

div.column{
    border-style:solid;
    border-color:rgba(56,43,3,1);

}



#content1, #content2,#content3,#content4{
    opacity:1;
    display: none;
    padding: 3px auto;

}

.clear-fix{

}
.column li{
    padding:4px 0 4px 0;
    margin-top:30px;
    margin-bottom:30px;
    font-family:'Oswald', sans-serif;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 20px;
    overflow: hidden;

}

.clr{
    clear:both;
    font-size:0;
}



.column{
    float:left;
    background-size: 220px 220px;   
    background:#5a4c1c;
    padding: 5px 2px;
    margin: 10px 10px 0 0;
    opacity:0.5;
    width: 15%;
    border-radius:20px;


}

.column li:hover{
    background: black;
    border-radius:20px;
}

.content{
    color:#5a4c1c;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-family: helvetica;
    width:85%;
}

.footer{

    text-align: center;
    background:#5a4c1c;
    color: white;
    padding: 10px 0;
    opacity: 0.5;
    margin-top: 30%;
    border-radius:10px;




   }

    <!DOCTYPE html>

    <head>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <link href="/normalize.css" rel="stylesheet"> 
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald" rel="stylesheet">
        <title> Resume: Ryan Anderson</title>
    </head>

    <header>
      <h1>Ryan Anderson</h1>
      <h3>Developer</h3>
    </header>


    <body>
     <div class="clearfix"> 
      <div class="column">
         <ul>
           <li id="about"> <span>About Me</span> </li>
           <li id='education'> <span>Education</span></li>
           <li id='info'> <span>Experience</span></li>
           <li id='ref'> <span>References</span></li>
         </ul>
        <div class="clr"></div>
     </div>


     <div id="content1" class="content show-description">
      <p>About me <br />
         <small>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Eligendi non quis exercitationem culpa nesciunt nihil aut nostrum explicabo reprehenderit optio amet ab temporibus asperiores quasi cupiditate. Voluptatum ducimus voluptates voluptas?</small>
      </p>
     </div>

     <div id="content2" class="content" >
      <p>Education <br />
         <small>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Eligendi non quis exercitationem culpa nesciunt nihil aut nostrum explicabo reprehenderit optio amet ab temporibus asperiores quasi cupiditate. Voluptatum ducimus voluptates voluptas?</small>
      </p>
     </div>

     <div id="content3" class="content">
      <p>Experience <br />
         <small>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Eligendi non quis exercitationem culpa nesciunt nihil aut nostrum explicabo reprehenderit optio amet ab temporibus asperiores quasi cupiditate. Voluptatum ducimus voluptates voluptas?</small>
      </p>
     </div>

     <div id="content4" class="content">
       <p>References <br />
          Paul Garven (co-worker): (780)-828-1111<br />
          Paul CWC (owner of CWWC): (416)- 721-1111<br />
          Someone at Bitmaker: (416-967-11-11
       </p>
     </div>
    </div>


    <div class="footer">
      <p>Contact <br/>
           <small>mobile: (647)-333-8723 <br/>
           e-mail: hotmail@gmail.com</small>
      </p>
    </div>

    <script>

    $("li#about").hover(function(){
          $("#content1").toggle();
    });

    $("li#education").hover(function() {
          $("#content2").toggle();
    });

    $("li#info").hover(function() {
          $("#content3").toggle();
    });

    $("li#ref").hover(function() {
          $("#content4").toggle();
    });
    </script>

    </body>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an error in your CSS.

```
#content1, #content2,#content3,#content4{
    opacity:1;
    display: none;
    padding: 3px auto; <--
}
```

padding doesn't take the value auto.

Switch it to `padding-top:3px; padding-bottom:3px;` and the jittering will stop.

Link: [Working proof](https://jsfiddle.net/cwn6ws02/5/)

Comment: Thanks, that helps. Much appreciate Ibu!

Answer (score 1):

you have some issues with your markup
some of your nesting is applied incorrectly.
in fact i am not even sure i found all the errors

some of your css is incorrect as well

```js
$("li#about").hover(function() {
      $("#content1").toggle();
    });

    $("li#education").hover(function() {
      $("#content2").toggle();
    });

    $("li#info").hover(function() {
      $("#content3").toggle();
    });

    $("li#ref").hover(function() {
      $("#content4").toggle();})
```

```css
header {
  background: #5a4c1c;
  border-radius: 10px;
  opacity: 0.85;
  padding: 1px 0;
}
.minheight {
  min-height: 200px;
}
h1 {
  margin: 0 0;
  color: white;
  padding-left: 10px;
}
h3 {
  color: #dad6c7;
  padding-left: 31px;
}
body {
  background: #dad6c7;
}
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0px 15px;
  margin: 50px 0;
}
span {
  color: white;
}
li {
  font-family: Helvetica;
}
div.column {
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: rgba(56, 43, 3, 1);
}
#content1,
#content2,
#content3,
#content4 {
  opacity: 1;
  display: none;
  padding: 3px auto;
}
.clear-fix {

} 

.column li {
  padding: 4px 0 4px 0;
  margin-top: 30px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 20px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.clr {
  clear: both;
  font-size: 0;
}
.column {
  float: left;
  background-size: 220px 220px;
  background: #5a4c1c;
  padding: 5px 2px;
  margin: 10px 10px 10px 0;
  opacity: 0.5;
  width: 20%;
  min-width:134px;
  border-radius: 20px;
}
.column li:hover{
  background: black;
  border-radius: 20px;
}
.content {
  color: #5a4c1c;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: helvetica;
  width: 85%;
}
.footer {
  text-align: center;
  background: #5a4c1c;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px 0;
  opacity: 0.5;
  margin-top: 30%;
  border-radius: 10px;
  clear:both;
  
}
```

```html
<link href="//normalize-css.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/normalize.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <h1>Ryan Anderson</h1>
  <h3>Developer</h3>
  <div class="clearfix">
    <div class="column">
      <ul>
        <li id="about"> <span>About Me</span> 
        </li>
        <li id='education'> <span>Education</span>
        </li>
        <li id='info'> <span>Experience</span>
        </li>
        <li id='ref'> <span>References</span>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <div class="clr"></div>
    </div>


    <div id="content1" class="content show-description">
      <p>About me
        <br />
        <small>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Eligendi non quis exercitationem culpa nesciunt nihil aut nostrum explicabo reprehenderit optio amet ab temporibus asperiores quasi cupiditate. Voluptatum ducimus voluptates voluptas?</small>
      </p>
    </div>

    <div id="content2" class="content">
      <p>Education
        <br />
        <small>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Eligendi non quis exercitationem culpa nesciunt nihil aut nostrum explicabo reprehenderit optio amet ab temporibus asperiores quasi cupiditate. Voluptatum ducimus voluptates voluptas?</small>
      </p>
    </div>

    <div id="content3" class="content">
      <p>Experience
        <br />
        <small>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Eligendi non quis exercitationem culpa nesciunt nihil aut nostrum explicabo reprehenderit optio amet ab temporibus asperiores quasi cupiditate. Voluptatum ducimus voluptates voluptas?</small>
      </p>
    </div>

    <div id="content4" class="content">
      <p>References
        <br />Paul Garven (co-worker): (780)-828-1111
        <br />Paul CWC (owner of CWWC): (416)- 721-1111
        <br />Someone at Bitmaker: (416-967-11-11
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>


  

<div class="footer">
    <p>Contact
       <br/>
      <small>mobile: (647)-333-8723 <br/>
    e-mail: hotmail@gmail.com</small>
    </p>
  </div>

</body>
```

Comment: Thanks for the input, much appreciate happymacarts!

Comment: regarding the CSS, could you point me in the right direction as to what is wrong with it? Not looking for an answer just, is it notation or just the method of going about it?

Comment: Regarding css I just read it wrong. There was an empty class for clearfix that I was reading wrong css is fine. Other than what was posted out about padding auto

Comment: Thanks for all the editing, you really didn't have to go through all that trouble lol. I just finished tidying it up, looks so much  better.  As for that footer moving around. I've been trying to tackle this problem, could you give me a clue. No answers. I've been fiddling with it and to no avail.

Comment: take a look at my snippet. the footer isn't bouncing there(clear:both). I also added a min-width to the column so when it colapses in smaller viewport the buttons remain visable

Comment: So I took your subtle hint and went through your snippet much more thoroughly. About three times. Still footer shifts. I took my code out of Rails and put it in JSFiddle: (https://jsfiddle.net/dgibbins1/zahd5wjc/1/)    Works fine.

Comment: Looks like you have it fixed. Glad to help. If you have any more questions you should post to a new question

Comment: Yes, figured this would be a new topic. Again, much appreciated for taking the time. Really impressed with the community here, so helpful. Cheers!